# wrench and gear settings is missing

Tags: network-manager, settings

I have been experiencing some issue with my network cable settings in Ubuntu 18.04. Because it is always getting connected and disconnected time to time. So I found a solution from this site saying

> It may just be an internal error. Try these codes
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge network-manager
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get install network-manager
> ```
>
> then reboot.
>
> to follow these steps.

I followed this step and it seems that my network cable is continuously connected up to now. But the issue is now I can't find my settings app  (wrench and gear) on the dock. Is there any solution to correct this?

Comment: this is confusing me sometimes... otherwise i'm not an idiot to post the same twice

Answer (score 1):

please try `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center` which is the cog and wrench program I have installed on 18.04